# Swap one element with all other in vector

Tags: c++, vector, swap

I have vector like this v = {1, 0, 1} I want to swap each element with other and return  a vector each time the two elements were sawp. For this example the soltuion should be:v1 = {0, 1, 1}, v2 = {1, 0, 1}, v3 = {1, 0, 1}. I did like his but I dit get the same result :

```
for (size_t i = 0; i < tempSol.size() - 1; ++i) {
    for (size_t j = i + 1; j < solution.size(); ++j) {
            swap(tempSol[i], tempSol[j]); 
            listSolution.push_back(tempSol);
    }
}
```

The result is : v1 = {0, 1, 1} , v2 = {1, 1, 0}, v3= {1, 0, 1} the difference in vector v2. Thanks for your help

Comment: Your question is unclear.  You have three items in the vector.  Which items are you swapping?  When are you swapping them?  Your "wrong" answer makes as much sense as your "right" answer.

Comment: I start by taking the firt element and swap it with all other, for example i = 0, j = 1 I swap the element swap(tempSol[0], tempSol[1])

Comment: Are you looking for `std::next_permutation`? (http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation)

Comment: **Why** your result should be as you posted and not what actually get? Describe steps which will lead to your desired solution.

Comment: Given this, what problem are you really trying to solve?  All of this swapping has to have a purpose to it.  So far, I don't understand at all your description --  this may be an example of an [X-Y Problem](http://xyproblem.info/)

Comment: No, my result is false. For this : v = { 1, 2, 3}  ---->  v1 = {2, 1, 3}, v2 = { 3, 2, 1 }, v3 = {1, 3, 2} (the correct result). My result :  v1 = {2, 1, 3}, v2 = { 3, 2, 1 }, v3 = {3, 2, 1} (error in v3)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem stems from the fact you are mutating your original vector, so later you are swapping already swapped values.

You need to:

1. Copy your vector on each iteration.
2. Do the swap on that copy.
3. Add (or, better, move) mutated copy into your list.

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you're code is correct but your logic is off.  In your desired result you perform the first swap twice, in the code's result it only does the first swap once, which I assume is the real intent.  It would be easier to conceptualize if the vector were a map with keys.  For example:
v = {one: 1, two: 0, three: 1} v1 = {two: 0, one: 1, three: 1} v2 = {three: 1, one: 1, two: 0}.
Or maybe you assumed i would be a pointer to the first thing in the vector and that it would move with the swap.  This doesn't work as implemented, it will continue to access the first element which will become 0 after the first swap.

Comment: The result should be like this : v1 = {two: 2, one : 1, three : 3}, v2 = { three: 3, two : 2, one : 1}, v3 = { one : 1, three : 3, two : 2}